# Is there a way to create a dashboard that only my client interacts with?

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, admin

My current client already had me build his site out using Nuxt. However, now he wants more control of his content so he doesn't have to come to me all the time to make small changes to copy. Outside of WordPress, I can't think of a great solution as to how to give him a personal user admin to dynamically update the site.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your Nuxt app for the frontend and have a CMS headless for the data, like Wordpress (only used to edit/add content via its headless part).

Otherwise, there is also a huge list of tools that could help you in the JAMstack ecosystem: https://jamstack.org/headless-cms/

PS: I recommend discussing about that upfront rather than afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

Yes wordpress will be best because it gives you more control on user roles, you can give them access of content what you want and remove access.

So i think wp is best go for it.